# Pandas split column after third instance of delimiter?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column which I want to split into 3 separate columns.

```
o_order_df
         expiry
0    27-Sep-2018-260-CE
1    27-Sep-2018-250-CE


o_order_df[['expiry','strike','type']] = o_order_df['expiry'].str.split('-', n>=2, expand=True)
```

I want to `split` the `column` on the third occurrence of `-`.

I keep getting an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> NameError: name 'n' is not defined

Expected output

```
o_order_df

         expiry     strike     type
0    27-Sep-2018    260        CE
1    27-Sep-2018    250        CE
```

I am able to `split` the column by delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `n=2` with [`rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html):

```
o_order_df[['expiry','strike','type']] = o_order_df['expiry'].str.rsplit('-',n=2,expand=True)
```

If performance is important use list comprehension with `rsplit`:

```
c = ['expiry','strike','type']
df = pd.DataFrame([x.rsplit('-', 2) for x in o_order_df['expiry']], columns=c)
print (df)
        expiry strike type
0  27-Sep-2018    260   CE
1  27-Sep-2018    250   CE
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Reading `rsplit` documentation now.